# DocuSign - Error Promoting App to Production

Tags: docusignapi

Im in the process of trying to promote an Integration App to our production DocuSign environment, but receiving the following error.

"Excessive polling does not comply with DocuSign"

Here's the endpoint we are calling with from_date filter and a custom field. The from_date and the clientID custom field values change for each request that is made. Yet we still get the excessive polling error. The DSACCOUNTGUID value does not change.

[https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{DSACCOUNTGUID}/envelopes?from_date=2020-09-21T15:33:08.160Z&custom_field=clientID=1201](https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/%7BDSACCOUNTGUID%7D/envelopes?from_date=2020-09-21T15:33:08.160Z&custom_field=clientID=1201)

Can someone tell what we are doing incorrectly? Thanks ahead of time.

Can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this article](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/rules-and-limits/)

**Polling rate limits**
For any specific envelope, polling status requests are limited to once every 15 minutes.

To avoid excessive polling, you can specify a span of time to poll in each Envelopes: listStatusChanges or equivalent listStatusChanges SDK method call. To ensure that you don’t miss any changes, we recommend that you request overlapping times in your polls or subscribing to Connect to get status updates for the envelope.

You should consider using webhooks instead.

Comment: What does this mean? "you can specify a span of time to poll in each Envelopes: listStatusChanges or equivalent listStatusChanges SDK method call" If Im reading that right it means to set a date? What were doing seems to be doing that..

Comment: ..and we are not requesting a specific envelope in the callout. :-S

Comment: Can you go your API Dashboard and paste a screenshot of your last 20 API calls with timestamps? (https://admindemo.docusign.com/authenticate?goTo=developerDashboard)

Comment: Note: Any polling violations within the 24-hour span will continue to cause a key to fail review. You will need to wait until a new 24-hour span begins to make new calls and to avoid polling violations.
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/go-live/troubleshooting/

Comment: Ok thanks. Starting after that 24hr period, do I need to wait 15 minutes between each of the next 20 callouts?

Comment: yes, or you can make other API calls that won't trigger this issue, just don't have the listEnbelope call again in less then 15 min apart - that's considered polling

Answer (score 0):

The ListStatusChanges call will generally trigger a polling violation if it is called more than once every fifteen minutes.

What query string parameters are you using and how often are you making that call?